# What problems can occur with WCF BasicHttpBinding using a 3G network?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, 3g

I have a Silverlight application communicating with a server over WCF using basicHttpBinding. It works fine over the web, but customers complain of "communications issues" over a 3G network.

Is there anything specific in WCF that can be tweaked to work more nicely over a 3G network? What is it about a 3G network that might cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using WCF over 3G and EDGE and there are no communication problems specific to the network.

The only errors I get are caused by the slowness of the connection:

- timeouts occur when the response to WCF calls take time or because the size of the response makes it long to download. Check [WCF timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229760/183386).
- the potential problems inherent to asynchronous calls are exacerbated. It is a good way to detect those synchronization problems by the way. If you're not on a slow connection, try using a bandwidth limiter like [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).