# configure wcf timeout in app.config file

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I would like to increase my connection timeout .
 I am hosting my WCF service in windows service.
this is my App.config file:

`

```
<services>
  <service name="Service.WebexClient"  behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8413/MyWebexService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

`
I would like to increase the time out, where do it put this configuration in the app.config file?

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement this on the server side (if I'm reading it wrong please correct me). How would a client application be able to know the connection timeout set on the server if they aren't able to connect in the first place?

Comment: I can only find a reference to a transaction timeout not a connection timeout in Programming WCF Services.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/timeouts-wcf-services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a custom binding, for example in wsHttpBinding:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig"
         closeTimeout="00:00:30">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Than use it in the endpoint

```
<endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig"
          contract="..."
          name="...">
</endpoint>
```