# Why is my service timing out?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0, windows-server-2003

I have a WCF service that hits another SOAP (3rd party) service.  Sometimes the SOAP service can take it sweet time returning data.  For that reason I increased the timeout for connecting from the WCF service to the SOAP service.  I made the following changes:

In the web.config of the WCF service:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
</system.web>
```

In the code when instantiating the SOAP service, I do the following:

```
service = new The3rdPartyService
{
   Url = "http://192.168.1.40:8080", 
   Timeout = 600000                // assuming this is in milliseconds
};
```

However, the calls still time out after about 100 seconds.  Sounds like I am not overwriting the timeout properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the 3rd party timing out at 100 seconds??

Comment: WCF Services have a number of different configuration relative to the binding that all have different timeouts.  see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/timeouts-wcf-services

Comment: @antar125 No, it's not the 3rd party because the exception is from my call to the WebService.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't increased the timeout on your WCf service, you'll need to do that in the WCF service binding on both your client and server end. Have a look here [Timeouts WCF Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/timeouts-wcf-services). Not sure about the third party soap call if thats the timeout source.