# Release connection of WCF service at the server side

Tags: wcf

I have faced the problem with the connection limited in WCF. My WCF service was hosted in IIS and my windows form application client connects to WCF. In the Windows_Closed event, I call the client.Close() method  to notify the WCF service that "I quit" but in cases of my client crashed, the connection between my client and WCF service still exists for a time, I simulated 10 crashed time then my app did not work anymore.

And the question is, how to release the connection between WCF and crashed client? because the maxConnections of the server is limited and equal to 10 for example.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the InactivityTimeout as Brijesh points out if you are using ReliableSession. Otherwise you should leverage the basic WCF timeouts.

See [Timeouts WCF Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/timeouts-wcf-services) for a description of how each timeout is implemented.

Timeouts are often an annoyance for developers, but this is precisely the purpose for which they exist.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of [Inactivity Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout.aspx) . Here server will automatically close connection if it doesnot recieve message during specified time frame.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of using code block in your client:

```
using(ClientClass client = new ClientClass){
//Call service here
}
```

This isn't really reliable so you may want to go for try-catch-finally instead. Make sure that client.Abort is called in each of the catch blocks.

Comment: finally block will not execute for certain type of crash, like powefailure, out of memory, stack overflow, ExecutingEngineException