# NullReferenceException: On WCF Server

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

The WCF Server is hosted on a Windows service. We are getting the following error Sporadically. I am sure that this is not an application error and is thrown within the WCF Framework when closing a connection. Anybody has seen this before and had luck fixing it please share. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Threading.Overlapped.Free(NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlappedPtr)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.Free()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.FreeOrDefer()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Abort(TraceEventType traceEventType, String timeoutErrorString, TransferOperation transferOperation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Abort()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Abort()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPool.AbortItem(IConnection item)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IdlingCommunicationPool\`2.IdleTimeoutEndpointConnectionPool.AbortItem(TItem item)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationPool\`2.EndpointConnectionPool.ReturnConnection(TItem connection, Boolean connectionIsStillGood, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

Following is the excerpt from the client side.

```
    public DateTime GetLastReferenceDataRefreshedTime()
    {
        RfaReferenceServiceProxy serviceProxy = null;
        try
        {
            serviceProxy = SafeProxy();
            return serviceProxy.Channel.GetLastReferenceDataRefreshedTime();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException exception)
        {
            Log.Error("Retrying after communication exception:" + exception.Message);
            return SafeProxy().Channel.GetLastReferenceDataRefreshedTime();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to look into the inner exception to get infos about where the exception was thrown

Comment: Are you running things async?  It could be possible that something else is depending on the connection on a separate thread and that's why you're getting an unpredictable behavior.  There could be a race condition and if you close connection before the other thread executes its routine, this happens.  Look through your code and make sure that you're checking for `null`.  Either way, we can't tell without the code.

Comment: Can you post the code on the service when you're closing the connection please?

Comment: @TomRedfern, Is it possible to explicitly close a connection on the service. I believe it is automatically taken care by the Timouts. [Release Connection in server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573077/release-connection-of-wcf-service-at-the-server-side).

Comment: @B.K. There are indeed async calls to the WCF services from the client. But on the client side I always make sure that I catch any Communication exception and safely clean the connection before creating a new proxy and calling the Method again.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a method on the channel from within a catch block. This is not advisable, and I would be surprised if this is not the cause of your problem.

If `SafeProxy().Channel` is returning null then this would cause the observed behavior. It's impossible to know without seeing the contents of the SafeProxy method.