# WCF Web Service Client Timeout Values

Tags: wcf, web-services, timeout

I am using a WCF web service client to send and receive SOAP messages from a non-WCF web service. I want to control timeouts but really confused by the different timeout settings presented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405809.aspx).

Is there a simple list of settings for a WCF client (regardless of the server--where I know if server has shorter timeouts they will rule!)? Does it matter by binding or contract (XmlSerizalizer or MessageContact) type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeouts WCF Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/timeouts-wcf-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen: [Timeouts WCF Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/timeouts-wcf-services)? I think that particular question/answer fits what you are looking for.